# React-Native-Fusion_Chart through time series

Tags: react-native, fusioncharts

`enter code here`I am using Fusion chart through time series plotting through multiple line, but it is always plotting a single line chart. so please help me if it is possible.

[enter image description here][1]

here is the data which I am using to create Fusion chart

`data = 

                    [
                      [
                        "01-Feb-11",
                        "Grocery",
                        8866
                      ],
                      [
                        "01-Feb-11",
                        "Footwear",
                        984
                      ],
                      [
                        "02-Feb-11",
                        "Grocery",
                        2174
                      ],
                      [
                        "02-Feb-11",
                        "Footwear",
                        1109
                      ],
                      [
                        "03-Feb-11",
                        "Grocery",
                        2084
                      ],
                      [
                        "03-Feb-11",
                        "Footwear",
                        6526
                      ],
                      [
                        "04-Feb-11",
                        "Grocery",
                        1503
                      ],
                      [
                        "04-Feb-11",
                        "Footwear",
                        1007
                      ],
                      [
                        "05-Feb-11",
                        "Grocery",
                        4928
                      ]
                  ]`



Schema : 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwDwv.png

Comment: Please share the endpoint URLs you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to render a multi-series chart

```
 yaxis: [
      {
        plot: "Sales Value",
        title: "Sale Value",
        format: {
          prefix: "$"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Here is a demo  : https://jsfiddle.net/ug0af52o/

Comment: react js and JavaScript it is working finew. but in react native itb is always plotting a single line . so please send me code in react native with multi line fusion chart through time series.